# Deprecation notice: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18 Fixed (React.s dom)

Tags: reactjs, dom

ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './react-router-dom' in 'C:\Users\nagendra\nagendra-website\src'
how to solve errors and what are the change?

how to solve errors and what are the change?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { BrowserRouter } from './react-router-dom';

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>


/*const root=ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(*/
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: Edit your question and please add a code into it !